# Get the strings from a List of QtreeView

Tags: c++, qt, qtreeview

I want to get the Strings from a List of QtreeView.

In my qtreeview i have:

```
   [*] Node1
        [*] Subnode1_1
            test_1
            test_2
    [*] Node2
        test_3
        [*] Subnode2_1
            test_4    
    test_5
```

and I want to get Strings:  test_1, test2, test3, test4, test5
To start a request in a database.

The only thing i found is get the String from the node you selected.

by : `Tree->model()->itemData(m_listOfModelIndex.at(0))[Qt::DisplayRole].toString()`

Thanks

Comment: The title of your question is wrong. You don't want to get a list of QTreeView* objects, but a QStringList (= QList<QString>) from one single QTreeView* (or even better, from one single QAbstractItemModel*, which is behind the QTreeView*).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
QStringList strings = extractStringsFromModel(Tree->model(), QModelIndex());
```

Implementation of extractStringsFromModel

```
QStringList extractStringsFromModel(QAbstractItemModel *model, const QModelIndex &parent)
{
    QStringList retval;


    int rowCount = model->rowCount(parent);

    for(int i = 0; i < rowCount; ++i)
    {
        QModelIndex idx = model->index(i, 0, parent);

        if(idx.isValid())
        {
            retval << idx.data(Qt::DisplayRole).toString();
            retval << extractStringsFromModel(model, idx);
        }
    }

    return retval;
}
```

This recursive function will extract ALL texts from your model. If you want to get "specific" data, then you should add some filtering. But basicly it will go through whole tree.

Comment: return statement is missing.  Other than that, the method is fine.